# Fix error - mount: only root can do that

Tags: 12.04, mount, virtualbox, lubuntu, root

I am trying to share folders between host OS and guest OS in VirtualBox as shown in this tutorial - http://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/virtualbox-share-folder-host-guest/

As instructed in the tut, I go into my linux (L-ubuntu) guest and type the command -

```
mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharedFolderName mountPoint
```

When I do this, I get the error - mount: only root can do that.

How do I become root and then execute the above command. I have a non-root solution here which I will try later - [How do I mount a drive so that it is readable by me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56531/how-do-i-mount-a-drive-so-that-it-is-readable-by-me)

Comment: try the same command but start with "sudo ".

Answer (score 3):

To run a command as root, use `sudo command`. (You may want to [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) to learn more.)

So: `sudo mount -t vboxf ...`

#### Creating the Mount Point for the Share

If you mount the share at `/media/sharename`, that directory must first exist. To create it, run:

```
sudo mkdir /media/sharename
```

You can mount shares anywhere; they do not have to be mounted in `/media`. However, these days it's common for filesystems mounted as root, especially if they may be attached and detached, to have subfolders of `/media` as their mount points.

The more traditional place to put mount points is `/mnt`. Either way--or elsewhere--will work.

#### Letting a Normal User Access and Change the Contents of the Share

If the host OS doesn't use a Unix-style filesystem--for example, if you have a Windows host running an Ubuntu guest--then you might want to specify what user you intend to give full access to the files in the share. Otherwise modifying the files (and possibly accessing them at all) will require you to act as root. You probably don't want that; you probably want to mount the share as root, but be able to access its contents as a non-rot user.

To do that, include `uid=1000` in the `,`-separated list of options issued after `-o`:

- If that's the only option you're specifying, no comma is required. Otherwise, all options should be separated with commas, *and no spaces.*
- Replace `1000` with your actual user ID. If you're the first user created on your Ubuntu system (the user created during installation), typically your user ID is 1000. To find out your user ID, run the command `id -u` in the Ubuntu system.

Comment: did that with mountpoint as /mnt/NewSharedFolder. I only see some text about options. There is no folder called NewSharedFolder inside mnt folder. How do I fix this ?

Comment: @bashboy To create a folder, use `mkdir`. This folder should probably be owned by root, plus you need to be root to add folders to `/mnt`. So use `sudo` with `mkdir`: `sudo mkdir /mnt/NewShareFolder`. I've updated my answer too, to discuss this.

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the source/book? This really helped resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the correct permissions use: `sudo mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharedFolderName mountPoint`.

From the [sudo man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html):

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user

Comment: did that with mountpoint as /mnt/NewSharedFolder. I only see some text about options. There is no folder called NewSharedFolder inside mnt folder. How do I fix this ?